Variant of Peas Floating on Top of Glass question
The original question is here: Probability for six peas to be floating at the top of the glass?
I was interested in the following variant of the question, and whether or not my solution was correct.

Suppose there are $n$ peas in the glass with $m$ floating on top and
$n-m$ sunk on the bottom. We assume the initial conditions that $n-m\ge 2$
and $m \ge 2$. At each point a random number of peas from 0 to
2 floats to the top and a random number of peas from 0 to 2 sinks to
the bottom. If at any point, there is exactly one pea at the top, then
it just sinks to the bottom with probability 1 and similarly if there
is exactly one pea at the bottom. What is the probability that all $n$ peas float to the top before they sink to the bottom?

Note that the modification is in the case where there is one pea at the bottom or one pea at the top since now that pea is guaranteed to sink or float to the top.
Let $X$ be the number of peas floating at the top. Then I think my modification allows me to say that $X$ is a martingale. If There are at least two peas at the top and at least two peas at the bottom then on average one pea moves up and one pea moves down, which effectively cancels out.
If there is only one pea at the bottom, then on average one pea moves down (random number from 0 to 2) and the pea at the bottom is forced to move up. Hence, we can now say $X$ is a martingale. Let $p$ be the probability that all peas float at the top in the end. Then,
$$m = \mathbb{E}[X] = p\cdot n + (1-p)\cdot 0,$$
and so $p = \boxed{n/m}$.
Is this answer correct? And is there a way to use martingales to solve the original problem? As far as I can tell, the martingale property holds in the original problem as long as there are at least two peas. But if there is one pea, then the property no longer holds since that single pea can stay with probability $1/2$. Is there a transformation one can apply to $X$ to force it to be a martingale and do some sort of similar calculation to the one above, to get the answer a lot faster?

You answer seems correct to me. Not sure if there's such a transformation.
